# Using Django to create Strava Webhook subscription

Tags: python-3.x, django, webhooks, strava

I am trying to create a Strava webhook subscription to recieve events from users who have authorised my Strava application. I was able to successfully create a subscription using the code in [this Strava tutorial](https://developers.strava.com/docs/webhookexample/). However, I don't understand Javascript, so can't adapt the code to my needs. I am therefore trying to replicate it's functionality within Python using Django.

My basic approach has been to follow the setup outlined in the Django section of [this webpage](https://blog.bearer.sh/consume-webhooks-with-python/), then replace the code in the file `views.py` with the code below. I have tried to make the code function as similarly as possible to the Javascript function within the tutorial I linked above. However, I'm very new to web applications, so have taken shortcuts / 'gone with what works without understang why' in several places.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
import json

@csrf_exempt
@xframe_options_exempt
def example(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        verify_token = "STRAVA"
        str_request = str(request)
        try:
            mode      = str_request[str_request.find("hub.mode=") + 9 : len(str_request) - 2]
            token     = str_request[str_request.find("hub.verify_token=") + 17 : str_request.find("&hub.challenge")]
            challenge = str_request[str_request.find("hub.challenge=") + 14 : str_request.find("&hub.mode")]
        except:
            return HttpResponse('Could not verify. Mode, token or challenge not valid.')
        
        if (mode == 'subscribe' and token == verify_token):
            resp = json.dumps({"hub.challenge":challenge},separators=(',', ':'))
            return HttpResponse(resp, content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Could not verify mode or token.')
```

The [Strava documentation](https://developers.strava.com/docs/webhooks/) says that the callback url must respond to a GET request within 2 seconds with a status of `200` and an echo of the `hub.challenge` json string. This function seems to do that. Yet when I try to create a POST request equivalent to the one below:

```
$  curl -X POST https://www.strava.com/api/v3/push_subscriptions \
      -F client_id=[MY-CLIENT-ID] \
      -F client_secret=[MY-CLIENT-SECRET] \
      -F 'callback_url=http://[MY-IP-ADDRESS]:8000/webhooks/example/' \
      -F 'verify_token=STRAVA'
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "resource": "PushSubscription",
            "field": "callback url",
            "code": "not verifiable"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

P.S. Please let me know if there's anything I can do to make this example more reproducible. I don't really understand this area well enough to know whether I'm leaving out some crucial info!